# Loading images with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, random

By clicking on the button , the random two pictures should appear of 12 included in two boxes.But something goes wrong.Need advice to solve this this problem.

```js
var startBtn = document.getElementById("start-button");
var imgBox1 = document.getElementById("firstBox");
var imgBox2 = document.getElementById("secondBox");


var images = [
    '/assets/img/pic1.png',
    '/assets/img/pic2.png',
    '/assets/img/pic3.png',
    '/assets/img/pic4.png',
    '/assets/img/pic5.png',
    '/assets/img/pic6.png',
    '/assets/img/pic7.png',
    '/assets/img/pic8.png',
    '/assets/img/pic9.png',
    '/assets/img/pic10.png',
    '/assets/img/pic11.png',
    '/assets/img/pic12.png',
    
];

function loadImages(imgArr){
    for(var i=0; i< imgArr.length; i++) {
        console.log(imgArr[i]);
        var img = new Image();
            img.src = imgArr[i];
        document.getElementById('output').appendChild(img);
       
    }
 
}
    


startBtn.onclick = function(){
    
imgBox1.style.backgroundImage = images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)];
imgBox2.style.backgroundImage = images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)];
}
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive.  "Something goes wrong", is not an adequate description of a problem.  Describe, in detail, what actually happens (including any error messages) and what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use CSS's `url` function when setting the background image:

```js
startBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  imgBox1.style.backgroundImage = `url('${images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)]}')`
  imgBox2.style.backgroundImage = `url('${images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)]}')`
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add a button with id `start-button` by which you want to click. Essentially you are clicking on nothing.

```
<button type="button" id="start-button" style="">Start</button>
```

Comment: It's highly unlikely that this is the problem with the code. The author showed no HTML at all, how do you know they didn't forget to include their script in the HTML as well? That certainly seems like a similar problem ;-)